# How do i ask a good method in my case(toast messeage)

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, yaml, toast

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Snack Bar',
      theme: ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.red),
      home: MyPage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Toast message'),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: TextButton(
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: Colors.blue),
              onPressed: () {
                Fluttertoast.showToast(
                    msg: 'Flutter',
                    toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                    gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
                    timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 16.0);
              },
              child: Text(
                'Toast',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
              )),
        ));
  }
}
```

- I have added `fluttertoast: ^8.1.2` in `yaml`

but, If I debug this, the emulator doesn't run.

The reason is that the Cocoapods version is not up to date.

But my `Cocoapds is 1.11.3` which is the latest version.

One more thing I don't understand is that the emulator works well when i debug it with code for `snackbar`, not toast messages.

If I clear `fluttertoast: ^8.1.2` from `yaml`, the emulator runs, but adding it causes an error message for the `cocoapods` version, so only the toast message is a problem.

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing issue with latest version, try previous version i.e. [fluttertoast: ^8.1.1](https://pub.dev/packages/fluttertoast/versions/8.1.1)  or [fluttertoast: ^8.1.0](https://pub.dev/packages/fluttertoast/versions/8.1.0) . which may resolve your issue.
As I found this kind or error in [repo](https://github.com/ponnamkarthik/FlutterToast/issues/404).